# Как в Kohana 3.3 добавить правило валидации модели на лету?

Tags: php, kohana, orm, kohana-3

Как в Kohana 3.3 добавить правило на лету? Т.е. например перед сохранением модели User, если выполняется некое условие, нужно в модель добавить правило city_id не должно быть пустым, пробую так:

```
if (Arr::get($data, 'val') > 0){
                ORM::factory('User')->rules(array('city_id, array(array('not_empty'), array('digit'))));
            }

        try {
            $this->user->update_user($data);
        } catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {
            $errors = $e->errors('Validation');
       }
```

Пропускает в любом случае, т.е. правило не срабатывает

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в класс `Model_User` какое-то свойство, скажем:

```
class Model_User {
   private $is_city_id_required = false;

   public function set_city_id_required($required) {
       $this->is_city_id_required = $required;
   }

   public function rules() {
      $result = array(
          // Здесь общие правила
      );
      if ( $this->is_city_id_required ) {
          $result['city_id'] = array(array('not_empty'), array('digit'));
      }
      return $result;
   }
}
```

и потом используйте его:

```
if (Arr::get($data, 'val') > 0){
    $this->user->set_city_id_required(true);
}

try {
    $this->user->update_user($data);
} catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {
    $errors = $e->errors('Validation');
}
```

Comment: Как я выяснил, для решения подобных проблем в Kohana есть внешняя валидация (extra validation)

Answer (score 0):

Для решения подобных проблем в Kohana, стоит использовать внешнюю валидацию: (extra validation)

Comment: Внешняя валидация требует особой обработки в `catch` или во view

 `$errors = array_merge( $errors, $errors['_external'] );unset( $errors['_external'] );`

Comment: Да, я в курсе, для вывода ошибок есть специальный view, делаю именно так, как вы написали )

Answer (score 0):

```
$errors = array();

$item = 1;
//создаем модель
$model = ORM::factory('person', $item);

$v = $model->validation();
//какое-то правило
$v->rule('name', 'not_empty');
$v->check();
$errors = $v->errors('validation');

if(count($errors) > 0) {
    //обрабатываем массив ошибок
}
```